# Generic container to store objects of a particular template in C++

Tags: c++, containers, generic-programming

I am trying to create a generic container which can store heterogeneous objects of type Wrapper< T> where T can be any user defined type. I have seen boost::any and other solutions, but i cant call the function foo() without recasting(i dont know which type to recast,information about T is lost.) it back to original type.

How can I reasonably implement a Generic container/use existing generic container to achieve this ?

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper{
public:
  Wrapper(const T& a):o(a){};
  Wrapper(){};
  //public methods
  void foo(){
     //do stuff
  };
private:
 T o;
};

class X{};
class Y{};

int main(){
  X x;
  Y y;

  A_GENERIC_CONTAINER generic_container;
  // A_GENERIC_CONTAINER should be able to store
  // any number of heterogeneous objects of type Wrapper<T>
  // where T can be any user defined type.

  generic_container.push_back(x);
  generic_container.push_back(y);

  auto it =  generic_container.begin();
  auto end =  generic_container.end();
  while(it != end){
    it->foo();
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will be of help. It's from the man himself: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#containers

Comment: thanks Nikos, but the problem is i cant use any or a vector of a common class - Wrapper<T1> and Wrapper<T2> are 2 different classes altogether - so no runtime polymorphism.

Comment: if i drop to (void *) I have to recast is to Wrapper<T> to use foo , where i have already lost info on T

Comment: vector<boost::variant<T1,T2..TN> > or boost::fusion::vector<T1,T2..TN> > will solve the issue, but only for the a subset [i.e. types T1,T2.. TN ]

Comment: Can you create a virtual base BaseWrapper, and then leave it up to Wrapper<T1> and Wrapper<T2> to define the implementation?  And how many functions do you need to expose in a generic fashion?

Comment: Boost::Variant + Visitor pattern is usually how people resolve such issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most generic way is to create a base class for Wrapper, say BaseWrapper, and define the pure virtual functions on the BaseWrapper that then are implemented on each of the Wrapper classes.  Through specialization, each Wrapper, Wrapper, could have their own implementation.  Once you've done that, you can use a container of a smart pointer to the Base Type, and use it at your leisure.

There are some possible shortcuts.  For example, in the simple case in your example, I would recommend using `std::function`.  A helper function aids in doing this.  Note, this really only works if there is only 1 method to be called.  I also would recommend having your wrapper define `operator()` directly, so that you don't have to use the bind.

```
template<T>
std::function<void()> wrap(const T& x)
{
   return std::bind(&Wrapper<T>::foo, Wrapper<T>(x));
}

int main(){
  X x;
  Y y;

  std::vector<std::function<void()> > generic_container;
  // A_GENERIC_CONTAINER should be able to store
  // any number of heterogeneous objects of type Wrapper<T>
  // where T can be any user defined type.

  generic_container.push_back(wrap(x));
  generic_container.push_back(wrap(y));

  auto it =  generic_container.begin();
  auto end =  generic_container.end();
  while(it != end){
    (*it)();
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Edit:

What I was discussing was a non-templated base, from which you derive all of your templated wrappers.  This allows you to call the methods you have pre-defined (and that must be implemented by the Wrapper), without knowing the specific wrapper type involved.

```
class Base
{
  public:
   virtual ~Base() {};
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Wrapper : public Base{
public:
  Wrapper(const T& a):o(a){};
  Wrapper(){};
  //public methods
  virtual void foo(){
     //do stuff
  };
private:
 T o;
};

int main(){
  X x;
  Y y;

  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base> > generic_container;
  // A_GENERIC_CONTAINER should be able to store
  // any number of heterogeneous objects of type Wrapper<T>
  // where T can be any user defined type.

  generic_container.push_back(std::make_shared<Wrapper<X>>(x));
  generic_container.push_back(std::make_shared<Wrapper<Y>>(y));

  auto it =  generic_container.begin();
  auto end =  generic_container.end();
  while(it != end){
    it->foo();
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Comment: :) Thanks Dave. your 2nd shortcut solves my problem. but i want to understand your 1st solution with a BaseWrapper class.

Comment: how do i create a cotainer of smart pointers to base wrapper ?
    vector<shared_ptr<Base<T> > >  wvec;

Comment: @biswa.panda: See my edit.  If necessary, you could add more functions to the Base and the wrapper.  In the case where you need more than 1 function per wrapper, this is probably your best approach.

Comment: Something like this could be used to implement a death row pattern, in case fine grained control is required for destructing certain objects, like when you'd want to destroy them in batches. I love it! Thanks!